# C# Regex matches aabbccddeeff as two aabbcc and ddeeff sets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

When I do this:

```
var m = Regex.Match("aabbccddeeff", "[0-9a-fA-F]{6}");
```

I get only aabbcc as result. Actually (using .Matches) there're two matches: aabbcc and ddeeff.

Why? This causes issues with DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute because it expects single match that covers whole input value.

How do I write this properly to get a single match?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Your current regex looks for a string that contains exactly 6 consecutive hexadecimal digits. There are two such consecutive substrings in this order so it matches starting from the 0th index and steps every 6 characters.

Comment: RegularExpressionAttribute calls Regex.Match and expects it to return single match with aabbccddeeff as a single result.

Comment: Then you need to use `{12}` not `{6}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to achieve here?

The regular expression provided will try to match a sequence of exactly 6 letters / digits. Since there are 12 consecutive alphanumeric characters in the input, there are 2 consecutive matches. `Regex.Match` returns the first one, and `Regex.Matches` both of them, exactly as they should.

If you want to assert that the *entire* text will precisely match the regex (since you are using it for input validation, I assume this is the case), so that the *entire* input string should satisfy `Regex.IsMatch`, change the expression to:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$
```

On the other hand, if you don't want matching to be restricted to exactly 6 characters, change it to:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]+
```

Or if you are looking to match 12 characters:

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
```

Of course, you might need a `^` and `$` around the last 2 expressions too depending on your needs.

Comment: AH! My bad. Need (two digits){6} here, I use only one. Time to go home ;-)

Comment: Just to clarify, I needed [0-9a-fA-F]{12}. Yes, nothing about regexps here, just myself thinking in wrong terms.

Comment: @queen3: Glad to hear it. Are you sure you don't need to surround that with `^` and `$`? For input validation, that is commonly the case.

Comment: No, the data annotations attribute takes care of that (it checks that match starts at 0 and has same length as input string).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for Match: "This method returns the first substring in input that matches the regular expression pattern. You can retrieve subsequent matches by repeatedly calling the returned Match object's Match.NextMatch method. You can also retrieve all matches in a single method call by calling the Regex.Matches(String) method."

If you only want the first match then you need to modify your regular expression. Try "^[0-9a-fA-F]{6}"

Answer (score 0):

Well. You are matching the character set 0-9, a-f, A-F 6 times.

If you want to match the entire string, group the expression. `([0-9a-fA-F])*`. If you want at least once result, replace `*` with a `+`.